# Set logged in user based on API response

Tags: login, rest-api, api, remote-login

I have an external application that I want to redirect to a page on a wordpress site. The page needs to be different based on who is logged in.

The application has an API endpoint which I can call to get the logged in user.

Basically, I need the following to happen:

1) When the page loads, the API gets called to see who is logged in.

2) If the user does not exist, an account is created. If the user does exist, their data is displayed.

Is this possible to do? I tried googling it and found nothing. I'm thinking I will want the API call attached to the `wp_init` hook but not totally sure.

Any help is appreciated and I can provide more information if necessary!

Answer (score 0):

`init` is probably a good hook to do the API call, if you need know somehting about the current WP user as the user is authenticated by that time. You can check the WP user login status with `is_user_logged_in()`, if needed.

Or if you need to do some redirecting, then `template_redirect` could also be a viable hook. If you just want to change the page template, then determine the correct template inside `template_include` filter.

WordPress has its own [HTTP API](https://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API) that you could perhaps use to make the API call by using `wp_remote_get()`. But I guess `cUrl` will work as well, if you prefer to use it.

If you also need to create a new user to WP and not just to your API, you can use `wp_insert_user()` and then use `wp_signon()` to log the new user in.

Here's a rough example regarding `wp_remote_get()`,

```
function check_login_status() {

  // if relevant to check wp login status
  // if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
  //   // do something
  // }

  $api_url = 'http://api.isuserloggedin.com';
  // defaults shown
  $api_request_args = array(
    // 'timeout'     => 5,
    // 'redirection' => 5,
    // 'httpversion' => '1.0',
    // 'user-agent'  => 'WordPress/' . $wp_version . '; ' . home_url(),
    // 'blocking'    => true,
    // 'headers'     => array(),
    // 'cookies'     => array(),
    // 'body'        => null,
    // 'compress'    => false,
    // 'decompress'  => true,
    // 'sslverify'   => true,
    // 'stream'      => false,
    // 'filename'    => null
  );
  $api_request = wp_remote_get( $api_url, $api_request_args );

  if ( ! is_wp_error( $api_request ) ) {
    $response = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $api_request );
    // if needed, decode the $response
    // $response = json_decode( $response );

    // do something with the $response

  } else {
    // api call failed    
  }

}
add_action( 'init', 'check_login_status' );
```